# facebook “Like box” in ajax loaded page only loads the first time?

Tags: ajax, facebook

I want to show the Facebook "Like box" plugin and some other FB code in a ajax loaded page.

When I load it in a ordinary html page it works as it should, but when I try to put it in a ajax load page **it only loads the first time**, when I click on the link to load the page the **second time it is not loading the page**? It is only loading the page if I clear the cache.

The index file init the fb code.

```
FB.init({
  appId      : '277065222', // App ID
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
  oauth      : true
});
```

I load the ajax page with this code:

```
 function loadFacebook(){

$('#container').load('http://www.manmade.se/manmade/guiden/facebook_onweb.html');
FB.XFBML.parse();
}
```

And in the ajax loaded page I have the facebook code, eg the facebook Like box.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly returns from the ajax call? What do you mean by "not loading the page"? That the ajax call does not work out or that the fb code is not being parsed?

Answer (score 14):

you can call fb par script in your page load after calling fb script

```
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=11111code";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    try {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    } catch (ex) { }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

reloadlike.html

```
<div class="fb-like fltLeft" data-href="http://yrl_like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="87" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

---

this should work every time.

I guess your callback is not right.

```
$('#container').load('reloadlike.html', function() {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still only show the page the first time.
Please see www.manmade.se/guiden.asp and there the leftsidelink at the bottom called. Facebook on web. I dont understand why it loads ir the first time, but the stop working. It show a alert everytime that is in the ajaxpage, but not the other stuff.

Comment: i have updated my previous comment. the ajax request should only content FBML like tag. In your facebookonweb.html all the html is there...so make fbml code separate for like reload only.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that in the facebook_onweb.html page I have both 2 Like boxes and some other facebook code that gets ex. albums from facebook with the facebook api.

Comment: If you look at http://www.manmade.se/manmade/guiden/facebook_onweb.asp you see that it loads everthing as it should when it is a seperate page(not ajax)

Comment: what i did is i tried next given script in firebug for your asp. i clicked many times any for all the times facebook pplugins are loaded correctly. $('#container').load('http://www.manmade.se/manmade/guiden/facebook_onweb.asp', function(){

FB.XFBML.parse();

});

Comment: Im testing in Safari and that doesnt load it..or perhaps it load it, but it is not displaying it...starting to get confused...have tested so many different things now...what do you mean with next given script?

Answer (score 0):

Varying a little bit the example code from bugrasitemkar, at the end of the ajax code, I include this jquery script and it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        try {
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        } catch (ex) { }
    });
</script>
```